# autocomplete form using Apex and VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, compile-error

I was working on the autocomplete feature for which I have this controller and page.

**Controller:**

```
public class autoCompleteCon {

 public List<String> listOfStrings {get; set;}

   // Constructor Beginning 

   public autoCompleteCon() {
      listOfStrings = new List<String>();
      for(Account a: [SELECT id, Name From Account LIMIT 10])
      listOfStrings.add(a.name);
      }
}
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page Controller="autoCompleteCon" docType="html-5.0">
 <apex:form>
  <apex:inputText list="{!listOfString}"/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But there is an error popping up in the page which says

> Unknown property 'autoCompleteCon.listOfString'

How do I proceed now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply misspelled your property. In your controller it is `listOfStrings` and on your page it is `listOfString`. You left of the `s`.

Comment: Maybe I'll be able to increase my typing speed one of these days.

Comment: @DerekF You were doing the hard part (editing) and I just happened onto the question right when you finished cleaning it up.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I surely will. Just waiting for the 5 min time period to be complete so that I can mark it. I did upvote it .

Comment: @DerekF Thank you.